# Complex IF statement issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, conditional-statements

There is a complex condition in an `if` statement and somehow it doesn't work out how I want.

```
if (
    (statementA1) ||
    (statementA2) &&
    (statementB) &&
    (statementC)
) {
    doSomething
}
```

Both `A1` and `A2` can't be true at the same time (because of the nature of the actual statement). 
Also, both `B` and `C` has to evaluate true in order to result in an overall true.
So only for `true false true true` and `false true true true` should return `true`; any other permutation should return `false`.

The statements are in braces because of their inner complexity (including `Math.abs()`, `A1` and `B` have inner, combined substatements).

Comment: If operator precedence is difficult for you, you can always split one if block into several nested. But yes, logical AND has higher precedence then OR.

Comment: `a || b && c` parses as `a || (b && c)`.

Comment: Its not too complicated, im just too fixated on this issue (rewrote the same feauter like 3 times this week) and at the moment i have noone around to discuss it with. Its pretty disgusting in itself without nesting anything inside.

Comment: Why not simply read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)? By the way, when you say *both `A1` and `A1` can't be true at the same time", I assume you mean **will never be**, not **must not be for the condition to hold**, right?

Comment: In other words, are you saying `true true true true` will never occur, or are you saying that it could occur, and if so, should return false (or true)?

Comment: @torazaburo trust me i read the documentation multiple times before i cry for help. now it seems pretty obvious to me as well. i guess i was too fixated on this manner which i think happens to everyone.

and i meant A1 and A2 never will be true at the same time

Comment: This is where that grouping by parentheses, square brackets, etc. your Math teacher taught you plays an important role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For

> ```
>   a1    a2    b     c   result
> ----- ----- ----- ----- ------
> true  false true  true  true
> false true  true  true  true
> true  true  true  true  true  <- different from blow
> ```

you can use this expression

```
(a1 || a2) && b && c
```

Either `a1` or `a2` and `b` and `c`.

```
if ((statementA1 || statementA2) && statementB && statementC) {
    // doSomething
}
```

You need the parenthesis because of the [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) of [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) (6) over [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) (5)

If you have the case

> ```
>   a1    a2    b     c   result
> ----- ----- ----- ----- ------
> true  false true  true  true
> false true  true  true  true
> true  true  true  true  false <- different from above
> ```

then you could use this expression

```
(!a1 && a2 || a1 && !a2) && b && c
```

which check `a1` and `a2` separately.

```
if ((!statementA1 && statementA2 || statementA1 && !statementA2) && statementB && statementC) {
    // doSomething
}
```

Comment: A1 partly and A2 fully refers to the same object property holding a string thats the logic behind. however I've tested with nina's solution and it gave me the proper results. I hope it wont be a problem to say thank you here.

Answer (score 2):

Remember the acronym "Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally", or PEMDAS, which refers to Parenthesis, Exponentiation, Multiplication/Division, and Addition/Subtraction. That is the order of precedence, from higher (tighter) to lower (looser), in many languages, including JavaScript.

A variant is "Please Excuse My Aunt" (PEMA).

Then remember that in the logical world `and` is sort of like multiplication, and `or` is sort of like addition. That way you can remember that and (`&&`) binds tighter than or (`||`).

Therefore, if you want to `and` together two conditions, one of which is itself `or`'ing two conditions, you must parenthesize the latter:

```
a && (b || c)
```

Without the parens, it would be interpreted as

```
(a && b) || c
```

Of course, in your particular case you can avoid worrying about precedence and parentheses by simply writing

```
a1 != a2 && b && c
```